# How to count total SELECT query requests for specific collection from MongoDB logs?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection "cars" and below gives me how many documents exist inside it:

```
let carsColl = db.getCollection('cars');
carsColl.count();
```

However, I need to know how many times the **cars** collection is queried in total ? Also, say if I have two cars x and y, may I know how many SELECT queries executed for 'x' vs 'y' documents?

I checked MongoDB triggers but they can only be created for **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, **REPLACE** and **DELETE**, but not **SELECT**.

Any guidance will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your question basically you're not looking to query documents in a collection rather looking to query on type of operations being done on **cars** collection i.e; on logs.

Where as your below code will give no.of documents in **cars** collection :

```
let carsColl = db.getCollection('cars');
carsColl.count();
```

As that's not what you're looking for, then try below :

**Steps :**

1. Enable Db profiling, by default your DB will log slow running queries that is any query that runs > 100ms, So you need to log all queries in this case. Execute below query to log all queries on DB :

   ```
   db.setProfilingLevel(2)
   ```

   **Note :** Doing this can effect your DB performance as it will be logging all operations, which might become an issue for Prod servers having high amount of DB calls. **Ref :** [manage-the-database-profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) . Also check on how to execute above query as it might need user admin access.
2. Now once you do above step, You can execute these queries :

   1. To get count of all read queries on collection **cars** which is inside **test** DB, try below query. Here `op: 'query'` refers to all find calls (Remember that aggregation is different it has `op : command`).

      ```
      db.system.profile.find( { ns : 'test.cars', op: 'query' }).count()
      ```
   2. To get count of specific queries : In this case let's say your collection has few documents with a field `carType : x` & few others has `carType : y` and you're querying on them like this `db.cars.find('carType': 'x')`, then :

      ```
      db.system.profile.find( { ns : 'test.cars', op: 'query' , 'command.filter.carType' : 'x' }).count() // will give you all queries on x

      db.system.profile.find( { ns : 'test.cars', op: 'query' , 'command.filter.carType' : 'y' }).count() // will give you all queries on y
      ```

**Note :** Basically you'll be giving your filter query over `db.system.profile.find()` to differentiate between your needed finds *(Vs)* all other find logs.